# Emacs HideShow and START marker inside a comment?

Tags: regex, emacs, elisp, dot-emacs

Need to work on lot of Vim-edited sources in Emacs, trying to mimic folding/hiding code between markers `{{{` and `}}}`.

Chosen HideShow mode installed by default with Emacs, with following configuration from `.emacs`:

```
(add-to-list 'hs-special-modes-alist
    '(enh-ruby-mode
      "\{\{\{"
      "\}\}\}"
      "#"
      (lambda (arg) (search-forward "\}\}"))
      nil)))
```

Above setting however only works when START & END markers are **not** inside a comment, so following example won't match above conditions:

```
# Module Name

# Start of block to be folded {{{
class Something
end
# End of block to be folded }}}
```

When `hs-hide-all` function invoked, it folds unexpectedly 2nd row, before `{{{` marker:

```
# Module Name...
# Start of block to be folded {{{
class Something
end
# End of block to be folded }}}
```

I've tried change START/END regexps to `"#.*\{\{\{"` and `"#.*\}\}\}"` but it makes no difference.
If I alter regexp for COMMENT to something different, START/END start to match, but this is unwanted as comments really do start with a hash char `#`.

How can I **match markers inside a comment** with HideShow ?

Thanks

Comment: The package http://emacswiki.org/emacs/FoldingMode hides and shows comments on the form `# {{{ text text`.

Comment: @Lindydancer Thanks for the link, I'll give it a try. However I'd welcome a solution without use of external modules.